# Typescript asynchronous decorators decorate synchronous methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-decorator

How to correctly identify synchronous methods that have been modified to be asynchronous when using asynchronous decorators to decorate synchronous methods.

```js
function AsyncDecorator() {
  return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
      await sleep(100);
      const result = await originalMethod.apply(this, args);
      return result;
    };
    return descriptor;
  };
}

async function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

class Test {
  // This function appears to be a synchronous function, but has been changed to an asynchronous function by an asynchronous decorator, but I didn't know that
  @AsyncDecorator()
  fun(): string {
    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}

const result = new Test().fun();
console.log(result); // Expect results: Hello World!  Actual result: Promise {<pending>}
```

Comment: Why not just mark `fun` as `async`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331761/14717905 This answer shows how you can identify the decorators a class has, perhaps you could do something similar but for the function?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Comment: @Hedgybeats I believe by "*how to correctly identify*" the OP means "how do I give them the correct type signatures", not "how do I find them in the code"

Comment: @Bergi Oh I see now... The word "identify" threw me off. Thanks!

Comment: TS does not allow decorators to mutate types, and this is unlikely to happen until and unless decorators in JS are stabilized.  If you really need something like this you'll have to abandon decorators and go for plain functions; it's still ugly and probably fragile but at least you can describe the typings kind of, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX74QW).  Let me know if you want any of this as an answer.